dotnet tests file generated only when parent process exists
Im running a process (c#, .NET8. xUnit) that creates a test environment (downloading tests, downloading and running applications needed for the tests etc).
When the env is ready the process runs this code:
        var args = BuildArguments(testPath, testsResultsPath, clientAppPids, _config.GithubBranchName);
        Console.WriteLine($"Running tests with arguments: {args}");
        var testsProcess = _processManager.RunProcess(true, "dotnet", args);
        var testCts = new CancellationTokenSource(_config.TestTimeoutMs);
        await testsProcess.WaitForExitAsync(testCts.Token);

The RunProcess func is implemented like so:
 public IProcessWrapper RunProcess(bool redirectOutput, string command, string arguments)
 {
    try
    {
        _logger.SafeLog($"Running process: {command} {arguments}");
        var processStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
        {
            FileName = command,
            Arguments = arguments,
            RedirectStandardOutput = redirectOutput,
            RedirectStandardError = redirectOutput,
            UseShellExecute = false,
            CreateNoWindow = true
        };
        
        var process = new Process
        {
            StartInfo = processStartInfo
        };

        process.Start();
        
        return new ProcessWrapper(process);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        _logger.SafeLogException($"RunProcess failed: {command} {arguments}", e);
        throw;
    }
}

this code runs the tests like so:
dotnet test C:\Windows\Temp\MyTests.dll --logger:"junit;LogFileName=C:\Windows\Temp\My_Folder\TestResults\test_res.xml" --verbosity normal --filter "test_name=my-test" --environment DATA_NEEDED_FOR_TEST=some-data --environment BRANCH_NAME=some-name
Once the tests are finished (successfully, failed or timeout) I expect the test logs file to appear. However - my problem is that it does not appear (only in windows, in linux it seems to work fine). It finally appears when the parent process of the test is finished and exists. I looked here and on the net for anything but with no success. I suspect it has something to do with flushing the process somehow, or because i redirect the output, or something to do with disposing the ITestOutputHeler (xunit logger) - but didnt make any progress. would appreciate any help.


just to be sure - what WaitForExitAsync does? 2) "it does not appear"- how do you check that? 3) can you please add a full [mre] to play with?


1 - WaitForExitAsync does about what it says - waiting in async fashion for the process to exit. not sut sure what other stuff is behind the curtain.
2 - I check the presence of the file with File.Exists(path_to_file) which is a built in function in .NET. when debugging - i also watched the UI (which is less reliable of course).
3 - I cant give a minimal reproducible example more than i gave - as the code around is just to long. I did my best to give all the important info that involves creating, running and waiting for the test process to finish. If i can share some more - id be happy

I can only make sense of the post if you meant "exits" instead of "exists".  Typical behavior of anti-malware, try it again with it temporarily disabled.

Found the issue - the redirection of the output made the parent process get some handle over the stdoutput of the child process - probably preventing it from flushing. when i turned off the redirection it was solved and the test log file was generated at the end of the test (child process) - as expected.
